# Adding JavaFX 17.0.2 into existing Java 11 Project IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

As part of a uni project, I'm trying to add a GUI to an existing Java project using JavaFX. The initial project used Java 11 and the JavaFX version I have is 17.0.2 but I just keep getting a lot of different errors depending on what I do. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA

Does anyone know how to add JavaFX to existing projects?

My lecturer is no help at all

Comment: You are probably going to need to do a new JavaFX project. Just use the ideas and classes in the new project. You can probably improve the classes by using properties instead of regular variables.

Comment: "I just keep getting a lot of different errors"... you should mention the errors you are getting.. otherwise nobody can predict what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Make a new project

[image]

I suggest setting up a new JavaFX-focused project.

IntelliJ offers a project template expressly for that purpose. See this documentation page, [*Create a new JavaFX project*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html).

Then move over any existing code you have. You can do so by drag-and-drop into the project window.

You will find the [*OpenJFX*](https://openjfx.io/) library has been included as a dependency. OpenJFX is an open-source implementation of [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX). OpenJFX is organized as a sub-project on the [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project, co-led by Gluon and Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've tried this and now get an error saying: 

`package java.awt is not visible
  (package java.awt is declared in module java.desktop, but module maptrix.wiseguide does not read it).`

Do you have any ideas what this is?

Comment: @Wpitchy I suggest you write another Question on that specific issue, after searching Stack Overflow thoroughly.